# How do I say that I can add value to the job in a correct English sentence?

Tags: word-choice

Can a person be beneficial to a job?
How do I say that I can add value to the job in a correct English sentence?

Comment: "I can add value to the job."

Comment: Make sure you use [this typeface](http://www.sansbullshitsans.com/) if you're going to get into buzzword territory.

Answer (score 0):

> **Enhance** *verb*:; 3rd person present: enhances; past tense: enhanced; past participle: enhanced; gerund or present participle: enhancing
>
> intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of.

**"his skill-set does nothing but *enhance* his qualifications to lead this mission"**

> *synonyms*: increase, add to, intensify, heighten, magnify, amplify, inflate, strengthen, build up, supplement, augment, boost, raise, lift, elevate, exalt
>
> see, Google.com [**Link**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=enhance+definition&oq=enhance+definition&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i20j0i7i30l3j0i20j0i7i30l5.23298.28485.0.39311.8.8.0.0.0.0.114.823.3j5.8.0.msedr...0...1c.1.62.serp..0.8.810.UdjggYu4DjY)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding value to the job, I would say that you add value to the company by excelling at the job.

Answer (score -1):

If this is going into a CV, I'd say it's better to describe how you'll be able to benefit the company, or increase its value. The job is part of the company, so you can't actually benefit the job, it's the company.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and while your post is helpful, it does not directly answer the original question. When you have achieved sufficient site reputation points, you will be able to leave a comment such as this one. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for an overview of how this site operates.